# Android, django, server interaction?

Tags: android, django

i am new to web development and had a basic stupid question about android django and server.
I am trying to make an android app, with database on Django.
my question is:
1. how do android,Django and server interact with each other? 
2. do I even need a server to create a android accessible db.

I apologise in advance for the basic stupid question, will greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create API to afford your Android app interact with Django. You can use Django Rest Framework or Tastypie frameworks to implement REST API for your Django app.